# view's query "was not run" while getting results

Tags: views

I'm working with drupal 7 and views module (7.x-3.11 version) and I'm getting a strange problem.

In the Views admin, when I run the query, I get a message **no query was run** while I actually get expected results. Moreover, if I add a filter criteria and run the query, the results are affected by this new criteria while I still get **no query run** message.

Secondly, I have created a custom module to use `views_query_alter` to modify view's queries. It never comes into the function on this particular view while it does for other views.

So, to summary, I have a **no query was run** message and nothing is passing by the `hook_views_query_alter` but query is run somewhere because I get some results and it is sensitive to filter criteria changes.

I really need to find this query and to override but I just can't find it.

Do you have any idea of what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

If your views having contextual filter using relationship, then you should check if correct relationship set in contextual filter.